# Outlook-VBA to open the containing folder of a selected task list item

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013, I use the "Task List" side bar:

- From the **Mail** screen, choose the **View** ribbon tab.
- In the **Layout** ribbon group, click the **To-Do Bar** dropdown, and select **Tasks**.

Mail items that I "flag" are visible in this list.

I would appreciate if someone could provide VBA code to open the selected task item's **containing folder**.

I have tried the following code ([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6d1a3319-a0dc-4ce1-814e-cdf0fa7b11f8/adding-a-right-mouse-click-menu-option-to-an-outlook-item-of-open-containing-folder?forum=outlook)), but it unfortunately has an error.

```
Public Sub GetItemsFolderPath()
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Msg$
    Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
    If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
    End If
    Set F = obj.Parent ' <---------- DEBUG INDICATES THE ERROR IS HERE
    Msg = "The path is: " & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf
    Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
    If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

### EDIT

The error only occurs when you are viewing a different top-level folder than where the flagged item is located, at the time you try to run the macro.

- For example, if you are currently exploring somewhere in your Exchange account, and the flagged mail item happens to be in some subfolder within your Exchange account, then the macro will work fine.
- Likewise, if you are currently exploring somewhere in a PST datafile, and the flagged mail item happens to be in some subfolder within that PST datafile, then the macro will work fine.
- But if you are currently exploring one PST datafile, and your flagged item is NOT inside that PST, but rather somewhere else like a different PST or your Exchange account, then the macro will have the error.

Comment: How do you run this macro?

Comment: Go to **File** > **Options** > **Customize Ribbon**.  Choose whichever tab is an appropriate place to add the button.  For me, in the dropdown list at the top right, I choose **Tool Tabs**, then select & expand **Task List**.  Click **New Group** and add a new group (I named my new group "Folder").  Select your new group.  Then from the left dropdown list, choose **Macros**.  The subroutine will be visible (must be declared with "Public Sub").  Select the subroutine from the list and then click **Add>>**.  After you close options, you'll now see your button in the ribbon when you click a Task.

Comment: Works here perfectly for Exchange accounts. What type of Outlook account do you use (where todo items reside)?

Comment: Wow it does indeed work on my Exchange Inbox (I didn't even think to test that).  All my flagged mail items are normally in PST files.  It seems like the problem is just for any flagged items that are located inside a PST file.

Comment: It actually works for me for POP3 accounts with PST files. Do your PST files belong to POP3 accounts or they just connected as a standalone PST files?

Comment: My PST's are just stand-alone data files.

Comment: @Lakey I tried your macro with Outlook 2010 (not 2013), a PST file an some tasks in the PST file (named "Archive"). It runs without errors and displays **The path is: \\Archive\Tasks**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MAPI_E_INVALID_ENTRYID error. It may indicate that your PST file is corrupted. Try to run [scanpst.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272227) utility to fix it and after that try to run your script again.

Also, you may want to try running the script for items in another PST file(s).

EDIT: It happens sometimes that Outlook **profile** is corrupted and behaves in a weird way. You can try to create a new Outlook profile.

Comment: I just created a brand new PST datafile.  I created a subfolder inside it and then moved 2 messages from my Exchange inbox to the subfolder.  I flagged the messages so they show up in the task list.  When running the macro on these messages, the same error occurs.  So far all my tries have been done on my work computer.  I will try again at home tonight.

Comment: Update.  A little more experimenting and I found out the error only occurs when you're currently exploring a **different** PST than the one the flagged mail item is located when you run the macro.  Please see the edit to my question for details.

Comment: Still works here. Ok, what is the bitness of your Outlook 2013 (32/64)? Also, what edition do you have (Office 365 click-to-run or standalone Office installation)?

Comment: And one more question: do you have Office 2013 SP1 installed along with the latest updates from Microsoft Update?

Comment: Also updated the answer with suggestion to create a new Outlook profile.

Comment: It is Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 (32-bit).  I tried the code on a co-worker's Outlook (same version) and his works perfectly, no matter which PST he is currently exploring.  It appears you are correct that something with my Outlook profile is corrupted.  I'm going to accept you as the correct answer.  Thanks for identifying the problem.